# Can the 'key' attribute (in reactjs) be counted on to force remounting of any component?

Tags: reactjs

When rendering a list, one should add a `key` prop to each element of the list.  This is described in the documentation as a "hint" at which child elements may be stable across different renders. Changing the `key`'s value will cause that element to be unmounted and remounted.

This behavior also currently works for any components, even ones that do not represent list elements, and is recommended by some React developers as a way of forcing any component to remount when necessary. Is this behavior, which goes beyond what is described in the documentation, a stable feature of the API that can be relied upon, or should it be viewed as it an implementation detail that is subject to change at any time?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm asking whether this is a good pattern to adopt in one's code, or whether it relies on an unstable implementation detail of the API.

Answer (score 0):

The key attribute is intended to differentiate similar elements.  Setting a new key would indeed force a re-render, but I'm not sure why you would want to take such a brute-force approach.  Without knowing more about the specific situation you're encountering, it's hard to give input on whether it's a good or bad idea, but in general, it is a "hacky" implementation that is going to undo many of the benefits react provides behind the scenes in regards to it's usage of the virtual dom.

In general, if you've gotten to a point in your code where you need to force react to re-render when it isn't doing so of it's own volition, it probably means there is a more fundamental problem with your code.  This would be a band aid solution to that deeper issue, even if it is a fairly stable and reliable band aid.

Comment: Here's a scenario where this might arise.  Let's say your app has information about books, and the current url is /book/1.  Now the user navigates to /book/2, and you need to fetch the data for book 2 from an API.  At what point in the lifecycle should you call the API?  You could put the API call in ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount, but for those to work, the Book component needs to be unmounted and remounted when the user changes the url.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you put that API call in the wrong place then.